# How to differentiate between Exchange default folders and Custom folders?

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am creating mobile client app for exchange server. I want to know  that is there any way to differentiate between exchange default folders like RSS Feeds, News Feed, Quick Step Settings, Notes, Sync Issues, Inbox etc from user create folders. As the default folders can not be deleted I need to find a way restrict the deletion option for folders in my application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the default folders have a [DistinguishedFolderId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580808%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) in EWS or [WellKnownFolderName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.wellknownfoldername%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) in the EWS Managed API - not sure how it's surfaced in Java though. So you could let users delete folders so long as the folder was not a distinguished/well known folder.